# Hide address bar in mobile device browser

Tags: html, css, mobile-safari, mobile-website

I know 1 way of doing this.

```
<body onload="setTimeout(function() {window.scrollTo(0, 1)}, 100)">
...
</body>
```

But this works only if the page is big enough to be scrolled. If the page fits the screen the above function wont work. How to hide the address bar in this case ? I need to get it to work with iphone, ipad, android devices.

Comment: In what browser does this code hide the address bar?

Comment: In mobile devices like iphone and android, the address bar takes up a lot space, space we can instead use for our page.

Comment: @Pekka — mobile Safari (although I think it may not work in the latest version)

Comment: It works on current iOS (5.1 [9B179]) running on 4s, tested 24/4/2012

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Maybe you can set the minheight on the body bigger. **480px** screen height in vertical mode + **60px** address bar height = 540px.

Example:

```
body { min-height:540px; }     
body[orient="portrait"] { min-height:540px; }
body[orient="landscape"] { min-height:400px; }
```

Comment: Thats a good idea. But setting min height may be an issue. Since I am accessing the page from iPad as well. If I set min height a little more than iPad's height, we would have a big scroll view for iPhone.

Comment: I'm not sure, but i think it is not possible to hide the address bar on the iPad. so you can just set it the the iPhone min-height.

Comment: This actually helped. I am currently setting min-height by getting viewport height of the screen and adding 60px to it.

Comment: I tried this. This works very well with portrait mode but not in landscape mode with adroid chrome 33.

Answer (score 15):

**iPhone:**

Works only if the mobile "app" is added to the homescreen (through the plus-icon -> add to homescreen)

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
```

I have no experience with other mobile OS'es, but a quick Google-search for *hide browser url bar android* resulted in a similar solution to yours, with a window.scrollTo.

Comment: Indeed, definitely not the solution if you just want people to go to your application url and use it right away.

Answer (score 1):

from http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/mobile-web-apps/remove-address-bar/ I found

```
function hideAddressBar() {
  if(!window.location.hash) {
    if(document.height < window.outerHeight)
      document.body.style.height = (window.outerHeight + 50) + 'px';
    setTimeout( function(){ 
        window.scrollTo(0, 1); 
        document.body.style.height = 'auto'; 
      }, 50 );
  }
}
```

*A bit modified*

works quite well in some browsers, but at least I cannot get it to work Android Chrome.

Answer (score -1):

Just Add '`BR`' at the end of the page. or you can use the jqueryUI with the `div height 100%`