# Hide address bar in iPad

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad, webkit

I know you can hide the address bar on iPhone/iPad/Android using the `window.scrollTo` thing. However, nothing seems to get rid of the address bar on iPad. The only workaround I found was to add a meta tag and then let the user add the page to their home screen.

Am I missing something? Can you hide the address bar on iPad safari using some other trickery?

Comment: Reference to [window.scrollTo()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117377/how-to-hide-the-address-bar-on-iphone) code.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, why would you want to do this? To me, it feels like an extremely horrible idea to muck around with the user experience of the users browser, and hiding the address bar themselves isn't very hard, is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems only be possible with the workaround you mentioned:

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
```

[Ref #1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855969/hide-address-bar-in-mobile-device-browser)
[Ref #2](http://www.quora.com/Mobile-Safari/Is-there-a-way-to-hide-browser-bar-%28chrome%29-in-iPad-Safari)

Comment: Yea, well I already had that in my question so it seems weird to accept this as an answer :)

Comment: But that really isn't  workaround. That's only a solution for homescreen websites.