# Hide address bar in iPad mobile Safari

Tags: ios, ipad, mobile-safari

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hide address bar in iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7449432/hide-address-bar-in-ipad)

I know that it is possible to add app to home screen and than it can be launched in full screen mode.

Is there any way to do it from browser without adding app to home screen?

If not, how can address bar sizes be handled or detected if app is launched with or without the address bar?