# adding html tags to the head to make remove title bar when making a web app

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to remove the title bar in my HTML/JS application/responsive site. The site is mainly responsive but is a one-page app. However, I want to remove the header bar on mobile and iPad.

I am already using:

```
window.scrollTo(0,0);
```

which works for the iPhone but not the iPad. From the readings I have done it seems that its possible to add some HTML head tags that make this possible when the page is added to the homescreen of the iPad? Is this true and if so what are the headers?

Comment: Use media queries. `@media only screen and (min-width: your-ipad-resolution-goes-here) and (max-width: a-max-if-you-want) {
    #header { display: none; }
}

Comment: how does media queries enable me to not show ipad title bar!?!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove Address Bar in Safari in iOS5?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7890003/how-to-remove-address-bar-in-safari-in-ios5)

Comment: @Dan is it the adressbar or a header? as in <html> type header, such as div or the header element?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hide address bar in iPad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7449432/hide-address-bar-in-ipad)

Comment: yeah i looked for hide title bar and not address bar - but thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been answered here: [Hide address bar in iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7449432/hide-address-bar-in-ipad)

It'll only be possible if the user adds a bookmark of your web app to the home screen and you have the following meta tag in your `<head>`:

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
```

Comment: i did search for that and didnt find it - thanks , just what i needed