# Hide Tabs and URL Bar on Firefox Android

Tags: javascript, android, css, firefox, fullscreen

I'm trying to set up Firefox on Android as makeshift 'Kiosk' to show a website as a simple display, and I'd like to remove the Tabs/URL Bar. I can do fancy scrolling to hide the URL Bar, but I'm worried a user will brush past it and cause the tabs to show - I'd really like them to be hard/impossible to access.

I've tried various kinds of CSS that would work on desktop to hide the URL Bar/Tabs bar, Javascript to auto-scroll the window to trick it, various extensions, changing CSS properties of the site to alter its height/max height etc.

Unfortunately, displaying this webpage requires the use of an extension I use to inject CSS, so while pinning the tab to home and opening it like that puts it in the beautiful fullscreen format I want, it unfortunately doesn't enable the extension I need to display it properly.

Is there any way to hide the URL Bar and Tabs bar, more permanently than scrolling a little bit? I have full control over the tablet and the app, including the ability to inject CSS and JS, but not the website itself.

Comment: Have you seen this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16180760/hiding-the-address-bar-in-mobile-firefox ?

Comment: Yes - The code seems to do nothing at all in Firefox for Mobile, in my experience.